# How Should I do to limit the value calculated by AVG or SUM

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I would like to make the result value of AMY within 300 .

```
example
270 -> 270
300 -> 300
350 -> 300
```

How should I modify it ?
Is it possible to use case when in Case when?

```
select 
no, sum(case when type = 'A' then cost else -cost end) * 0.08 as AMY 
from MIKE
where 
MIKE.type in ('A', 'B') 
and exists (select 1 from users u where u.no = c.otaku_no)
group by no
```

Comment: Please tag your question with *one* database, the one you are really using.

Comment: I am using Oracle db..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `least()`:

```
   least(sum(case when type = 'A' then cost else -cost end) * 0.08, 300) as AMY
```

If the `sum()` exceeds 300, then the return value is `300`.  You can use `greatest()` if you want to impose a minimum.  So, this would ensure that the value is between -300 and 300:

```
   greatest(least(sum(case when type = 'A' then cost else -cost end) * 0.08, 300), -300) as AMY
```

Comment: awesome Thank you.